# Hyperbolic Intercept (Thales) Theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

Is there an Intercept theorem (from Thales, but don't mistake it with the Thales theorem in a circle) in hyperbolic geometry?

**Euclidean Intercept Theorem:**
Let S,A,B,C,D be 5 points, such that SA, SC, AC are respectively parallel to SB, SD, BD; and SB > SA, SD > SC. Then, we have SB/SA = SD/SC = BD/AD

[(see wiki illustration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6KOC.png)

**Hyperbolic Intercept Theorem?** The concept of parallel lines is tricky here... Let's place ourselves in the Klein model, consider a triangle $0xy$, two positive real numbers $p,q$, and construct the Einstein midpoints $x'=m(x,0;p,q)$ and $y'=m(y,0;p,q)$, defined by $$m(a,b;p,q)=\dfrac{p\gamma_a a+q\gamma_b b}{p\gamma_a +q\gamma_b},$$
with $\gamma_x=1/\sqrt{1-||x||^2}$ the Lorentz factor. The analogue of ``parallel lines'' here resides in that we use the same $(p,q)$ for $x$ and $y$. Then, I can prove that $$\dfrac{\sinh d(x',0)}{\sinh d(x,x')}= \dfrac{\sinh d(y',0)}{\sinh d(y,y')},$$
and I can also prove using hyperbolic sine law hat 
\begin{equation}
\sinh d(x',y') \leq\min \left(\dfrac{\sinh d(x',0)}{\sinh d(x,0)}\dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\sin \alpha'},\dfrac{\sinh d(y',0)}{\sinh d(y,0)}\dfrac{\sin \beta}{\sin \beta'}   \right)\sinh d(x,y).
\end{equation}
and I want to prove that either $\dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\sin \alpha'}  \leq 1$ or $\dfrac{\sin \beta}{\sin \beta'}\leq 1$. Here $\alpha,\beta$ are the angles at $x$ and $y$ in $Oxy$, and $\alpha',\beta'$ at $x'$ and $y'$ in $Ox'y'$.

Exploiting negative curvature, I could already prove that $\alpha+\beta < \alpha'+\beta'$, but that's not enough...

I would also be happy with a proof that Einstein midpoint operations are contracting (in $\sinh$ of distance), when we use the same weights $(p,q)$.

Edit: Note that we have the result we wanted when both $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are smaller than a right angle. The tricky part is when one of them isn't. In Euclidean space, the lines would be parallel and we could conclude using the converse of the Intercept Theorem. Here, we can't... Note also that the wiki illustration gives a quick proof in the Euclidean case which could help, but I did not manage to adapt it: [link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#Claim_2).

Comment: Who are "Einstein midpoints"?

Comment: Can you restate the problem in the Poincare model?

Comment: Einstein midpoints can be shown to be intrinsic to hyperbolic spaces, i.e. independent of the model, even though they only look nice to write in the Klein model. See the book Analytic hyperbolic geometry: Mathematical foundations and applications, by A. Ungar. Everything written above holds in the Poincare model since I am using intrinsic angles (except for the definition of m).

Comment: @tisydi - Could you then explain how they are defined in Riemannian geometry terms?

Comment: [Ungar - Analytic hyperbolic geometry: Mathematical foundations and applications](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/5914) ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=MawEKL8uqc0C); [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2169236)).  (Not answering @RW; I just like to have clickable links to papers and books.)